# First page margin different from others

Tags: margins, geometry, ieeetran, paper-size

I am finishing up paper formatting for final submission to IEEE conference for which I need to adjust the margins of other pages slightly different from page 1.

The conference recommends the following paper margins:

```
|---------------------|------------------------------------|
|US Letter first page |Top 72 Left 54 Right 54 Bottom 54 pt|
|---------------------|------------------------------------|
|US Letter other pages|Top 54 Left 54 Right 54 Bottom 54 pt|
|---------------------|------------------------------------|
```

Currently I set all margins to be the same as:

```
\usepackage[top=72pt, left=54pt, right=54pt, bottom=54pt]{geometry}
```

But I need other pages to be `54 pt` on all margins.

**EDIT**

Source Code for a `MWE`:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[left=54pt, right=54pt, bottom=54pt, top=54pt]{geometry}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
    
    
\begin{document}


\vspace*{18pt}
\title{The paper´s title here
\thanks{Acknowledgements.}
}

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{First Author\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}\IEEEauthorrefmark{3}, Second Author\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}\IEEEauthorrefmark{3}, and Third Author\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}\IEEEauthorrefmark{3}}

\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}First Affiliation \\
\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}Second Affiliation \\
\IEEEauthorrefmark{3}Third Affiliation \\
Email: first@email.com, second@email.com, third@email.com 
}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
This document is a model and instructions for \LaTeX.
This and the IEEEtran.cls file define the components of your paper [title, text, heads, etc.]. *CRITICAL: Do Not Use Symbols, Special Characters, Footnotes, 
or Math in Paper Title or Abstract.
\end{abstract}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
component, formatting, style, styling, insert
\end{IEEEkeywords}

\section{Introduction}
This document is a model and instructions for \LaTeX.
Please observe the conference page limits. 

\blindtext[5]

\section{Ease of Use}


\begin{thebibliography}{00}
\bibitem{b1} G. Eason, B. Noble, and I. N. Sneddon, ``On certain integrals of Lipschitz-Hankel type involving products of Bessel functions,'' Phil. Trans. Roy. Soc. London, vol. A247, pp. 529--551, April 1955.
\bibitem{b2} J. Clerk Maxwell, A Treatise on Electricity and Magnetism, 3rd ed., vol. 2. Oxford: Clarendon, 1892, pp.68--73.
\bibitem{b3} I. S. Jacobs and C. P. Bean, ``Fine particles, thin films and exchange anisotropy,'' in Magnetism, vol. III, G. T. Rado and H. Suhl, Eds. New York: Academic, 1963, pp. 271--350.
\bibitem{b4} K. Elissa, ``Title of paper if known,'' unpublished.
\bibitem{b5} R. Nicole, ``Title of paper with only first word capitalized,'' J. Name Stand. Abbrev., in press.
\bibitem{b6} Y. Yorozu, M. Hirano, K. Oka, and Y. Tagawa, ``Electron spectroscopy studies on magneto-optical media and plastic substrate interface,'' IEEE Transl. J. Magn. Japan, vol. 2, pp. 740--741, August 1987 [Digests 9th Annual Conf. Magnetics Japan, p. 301, 1982].
\bibitem{b7} M. Young, The Technical Writer's Handbook. Mill Valley, CA: University Science, 1989.
\end{thebibliography}
\vspace{12pt}
\color{red}
IEEE conference templates contain guidance text for composing and formatting conference papers. Please ensure that all template text is removed from your conference paper prior to submission to the conference. Failure to remove the template text from your paper may result in your paper not being published.

\end{document}
```

Output
[image]

Comment: set it to 54pt and put `\vspace*{18pt}` at the start of the document.

Comment: This adds a new black page at the beginning of ducument instead.

Comment: If you add the space at the right place it won't but with no code supplied hard to tell you exactly where to place this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [the `IEEEtran.cls` code](https://mirror.las.iastate.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran.cls), there are existing macros for defining margins, including special margins for the first page / header.

`\IEEEsettopmargin{t}{54pt}` (0.75in) is already the default in conference style.

But the default additional space for the title is given by `\def\IEEEtitletopspace{0.5\baselineskip}` which works out to 6pt in your style.  (You can figure this out via `\showthe\baselineskip` which shows 12pt.)

So to get the desired margins, you just need `\def\IEEEtitletopspace{18pt}`.

Complete example:

```latex
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\def\IEEEtitletopspace{18pt}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}


\begin{document}


\title{The paper´s title here
\thanks{Acknowledgements.}
}

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{First Author\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}\IEEEauthorrefmark{3}, Second Author\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}\IEEEauthorrefmark{3}, and Third Author\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}\IEEEauthorrefmark{3}}

\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}First Affiliation \\
\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}Second Affiliation \\
\IEEEauthorrefmark{3}Third Affiliation \\
Email: first@email.com, second@email.com, third@email.com
}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
This document is a model and instructions for \LaTeX.
This and the IEEEtran.cls file define the components of your paper [title, text, heads, etc.]. *CRITICAL: Do Not Use Symbols, Special Characters, Footnotes,
or Math in Paper Title or Abstract.
\end{abstract}


\begin{IEEEkeywords}
component, formatting, style, styling, insert
\end{IEEEkeywords}

\section{Introduction}
This document is a model and instructions for \LaTeX.
Please observe the conference page limits.

\blindtext[5]

\section{Ease of Use}


\begin{thebibliography}{00}
\bibitem{b1} G. Eason, B. Noble, and I. N. Sneddon, ``On certain integrals of Lipschitz-Hankel type involving products of Bessel functions,'' Phil. Trans. Roy. Soc. London, vol. A247, pp. 529--551, April 1955.
\bibitem{b2} J. Clerk Maxwell, A Treatise on Electricity and Magnetism, 3rd ed., vol. 2. Oxford: Clarendon, 1892, pp.68--73.
\bibitem{b3} I. S. Jacobs and C. P. Bean, ``Fine particles, thin films and exchange anisotropy,'' in Magnetism, vol. III, G. T. Rado and H. Suhl, Eds. New York: Academic, 1963, pp. 271--350.
\bibitem{b4} K. Elissa, ``Title of paper if known,'' unpublished.
\bibitem{b5} R. Nicole, ``Title of paper with only first word capitalized,'' J. Name Stand. Abbrev., in press.
\bibitem{b6} Y. Yorozu, M. Hirano, K. Oka, and Y. Tagawa, ``Electron spectroscopy studies on magneto-optical media and plastic substrate interface,'' IEEE Transl. J. Magn. Japan, vol. 2, pp. 740--741, August 1987 [Digests 9th Annual Conf. Magnetics Japan, p. 301, 1982].
\bibitem{b7} M. Young, The Technical Writer's Handbook. Mill Valley, CA: University Science, 1989.
\end{thebibliography}
\vspace{12pt}
\color{red}
IEEE conference templates contain guidance text for composing and formatting conference papers. Please ensure that all template text is removed from your conference paper prior to submission to the conference. Failure to remove the template text from your paper may result in your paper not being published.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, thank you so much. It works!

Answer (score 0):

Given how close the margins are, the easy way is to use `geometry` to set to the minimum margins globally:

```latex
\usepackage[top=54pt, left=54pt, right=54pt, bottom=54pt]{geometry}
```

and then manually add spacing to fix the margin on the first page.  72 − 54 = 18, so add `\vspace*{18pt}` at the top of your document.

Alternatively, `\AtBeginDocument{\vspace*{18pt}}` may work. See [this previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/513288/trigger-a-newgeometry-starting-at-a-certain-page).

Or try putting `\vspace*{18pt}` just within `\title{`.

Are you sure there isn't an IEEE style file for the conference that does this for you?

Comment: Of course I'm using the IEEE's  `IEEEtran` document class (provided template). But on the pdf-test page, I can see that all other pages leave spaces. If I can adjust these spaces, what's left in my extra page could fit, avoiding extra charges.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to adjust the `top` setting to `54pt` instead of `72pt`. Does that give what you want?

Comment: `IEEEtran` should set the margins for you.  Did you try omitting `geometry` altogether?

Comment: omitting the package causes some errors on pdf test: `Margin impositions: Page 1 has margin impositions Page 5 has margin impositions Page 6 has margin impositions`

Comment: We'd need to see a full example to understand what's going on...

Comment: Question edited to give a MWE.